# Spark Structured streaming application is failing with exit code : 100

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We have spark structured streaming application and doing some processing before writing the data into Sink. The application has been running without any issues  for 5-7 Days , but after application is terminating with exit code 100 . I am sending the log4j properties( sending same file to Driver and executor)  to the spark application as below.

Spark Version : 2.4.0

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,rolling
log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.rolling.file=/var/tmp/${app.logging.name}_driver.log
log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=${app.logging.level}
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
```

```
Application application_1572644938702_751093 failed 1 times (global limit =2; local limit is =1) due to AM Container for appattempt_1572644938702_751093_000001 exited with exitCode: -100
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* nodeFor more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://ip-xx-xx-xx-xx-ec2.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1572644938702_751093 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
```

Comment: how do you deploy your spark streaming code?  yarn cluster, yarn client?

Comment: I am executing the application as Yarn cluster mode [--deploy-mode cluster]

Comment: any logs in the application tracking page?